# Score function in rock paper scissors python issue and others

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I am new to programming & trying to create a best of 5 RPS game for my class but running into a few problems...when I call my score function that I created alternativley, it works but it then makes it so my while loop just keeps going, when I dont call the score function the while loops does stop at 3

```
 def gamerps():
        import random
        YS= 0
        CS= 0
        rules = {("R", "S"), ("P", "R"), ("S", "P")}
        msgs = {"R": "rock beats scissors", "P": "paper covers rock", "S":" scissors cut paper"}
        while YS or CS <= 3:
            YM = input("R/P/S?")
            CM = random.choice(["R", "P", "S"])
            if (YM, CM) in rules:
                print ("You won! %s" % (msgs[YM]))
                YS= YS+1
                print (scorerps(YS, CS))
            elif (CM, YM) in rules:
                print ("You lost! %s" % (msgs[CM]))
                CS= CS+1
                print (scorerps(YS, CS))
            elif YM == CM:
                print ("Tie! Go again!")
            else:
                print ("ERROR, please choose R, P, or S for [R]ock [P]aper [S]cissors")

gamerps()
```

---

the score function works fine on its own and it does add the score throughout the rps game when applied, it just makes the game no longer stop at first to 3....

```
def scorerps(YS, CS):
        if YS==CS:
            print("scores are tied at", YS, "-", CS, "!")
        elif YS >CS:
            if YS==3:
                print("You won ", YS, "-", CS,"!")
            else:
                print("You lead ", YS, "-", CS,"!")
        elif CS>YS:
            if CS==3:
                print("Computer won ", CS, "-", YS,"!")
            else:
                print("computer leads ", CS, "-", YS,"!")

    scorerps(1, 2)
```

Comment: why do you call `scorerps` **inside** itself? Also your `while` condition in `gamerps` is not what you think it is. It should be `while YS <= 3 and CS <= 3:`

Comment: oh ya should be "and"! &when you say call scorerps inside itself, do you mean in the 2nd code where I call score(1,2)?or in the RPS function when I call to print the score? I am calling score function(1,2) to test it,but what Im trying to do for assignment, is call the score function to display score in the RPS function, which has to be a seperate function, so I cant just add the code from score def in the RPS def, as we have to actually create seperatley then call it in the RPS function... if that makes sense, I might be misunderstanding what youre asking though...

Comment: I meant that inside the function `scorerps` the last line of the function is `scorerps(1 ,2)` so basically you have infinite recursion calls

Comment: ohh I see!, i think that formatting got messed up in here somehow but wasnt initially like that, lol thanks I didnt notice that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the condition of your `while` loop:

`while YS or CS <= 3:`

means that the loop is running as long as `YS != 0` or `CS <= 3` and this is probably not what you wanted.

You probably wanted the loop to run until one of the variables exceeds `3` so you have to use `and` anyway:

`while YS <= 3 and CS <= 3:`

=> This way the condition becomes `False` when **one** of the variables gets `> 3`

Keep in mind that this also means you need to win `4` rounds in order to win the game, because `<= 3` is still `True` after one side won its 3rd round. So you might want to check for `< 3`

Comment: THIS FIXED IT THX! however when it is print my results, everything is right except it is printing this "none" after every score, no idea why...R/P/S?P
You won! paper covers rock
You lead  2 - 1 !
None

R/P/S?S
Tie! Go again!

R/P/S?R
You lost! paper covers rock
scores are tied at 2 - 2 !
None

R/P/S?R
You won! rock beats scissors
You won  3 - 2 !
None

Comment: anyone know what the none is about??

Comment: Actually nvm I figured out the "none"  I guess I just call the score function not print it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be your while loop :

```
while YS or CS <= 3:
```

Any number which is not zero is true. Your loop condition is equivalent to

```
(YS != 0) or (CS <= 3)
```

This will break if the computer reaches 3 but not for the human.